# Scrumban + Gantt diagram?

Tags: scrum, gantt-chart, kanban

I have a project, and my team and I have decided to use Scrumban where we use Kanban for "To do" list, "progress," which is WIP, and "Done."

However, as we understand Kanban, I've read somewhere that Gantt diagrams do not go well with Kanban, and if that is the case, I want to know why.

We want to use the Gantt diagram to see a process of "how we will work throughout the project." So my question is, can we use the Kanban board system and Gantt diagram together? or is that completely unnecessary.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not to do with computer programming

Comment: @Lillie - I would suggest posting this over on pm.stackexchange.com - that is the more appropriate place and you'll get good answers there.

Answer (score 0):

Wen working in an Agile framework, a chart with remaining efforts will bring more value and clarity compared to a GANTT chart.